# How to implement the same Launcher icon on all Android Devices?

Tags: android, icons, launcher, adaptive-icon

Recently, I am implementing the adaptive launcher icon in my android application. I have successfully implemented it.

I ran my application on some Gionee mobile( mostly i run my application on Stock Android) running on customized Android 6.0 like mi or Huawei. I found out that there is some kind of ugly mask the manufacturer has embedded in the customized Android which makes the App Icons ugly.

So, I downloaded other apps and found out that other apps also have this ugly mask but apps like Google Tez, Google PlayStore, and many other Google apps are somehow defying this ugly mask thing making their icons like the original. How are they doing it?

I thought by putting their launcher icons into mine could put an end to my misery and I will somehow get the insight of making the launcher icon more compatible.

Here is the result of putting Tez icon in my resource file.

[image]

As you can see there is that ugly mask in my icon on the left of google chrome and the right one is the original Tez app icon. How are they doing it?

Comment: If this only happens on few popular apps (google, facebook etc) especially if they came preinstalled with the device, they might be hard-coded as an exception within the launcher app itself and You won't be able to work around that.

Comment: Facebook's legacy icon is square which is not the case of Google's apps. Google Tez, it's a payment application and it came around months ago but I had this device since last year. It didn't come pre-installed with the device. I explicitly downloaded it from the Playstore.

Comment: But Google didn't come out last month - it's enough to let all apps with package starting from "com.google" display defaults. You can try creating test app spoofing that package name and see if it displays normal icon.

Comment: Yeah, I tried but nothing happened. But my question was how they do that?